Is there a way to improve this query showing a monthly timeline of the number of active employees?
I have a Microsoft SQL database with all past and present employees with their start and leave date. I would like to know how many employees were active each month in the past years.
While I did find a solution, I was wondering if there is a better one. I eventually want to create a dashboard with not just this one timeline but lots of similar ones and always aggregating the data in the way I did seems too complex.
Here is an example table similar to the one I want to use:



employee_id
first_name
last_name
start_date
leave_date




1
Example
User
2022-12-28
2023-05-30


2
Second
Example
2023-01-14
2023-12-31


3
Third
Try
2023-02-05
2024-04-15



This is the script I wrote. It gives the correct results I think, however, it seems quite complicated to me for something I thought was a pretty straight forward requirement.
DECLARE @startDate date = '2022-11-01';

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    month_ date,
    nb_employees int
)

WHILE @startDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp
        SELECT @startDate, COUNT(employee_id)
        FROM employee_example
        WHERE 1=1
            AND (YEAR(start_date) < YEAR(@startDate)
            OR (YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(@startDate) AND MONTH(start_date) <= MONTH(@startDate)))
            AND (YEAR(leave_date) > YEAR(@startDate)
            OR (YEAR(leave_date) = YEAR(@startDate) AND MONTH(leave_date) >= MONTH(@startDate)))


    SET @startDate = DATEADD(month,1,@startDate)
END

SELECT * FROM #temp

DROP TABLE #temp

The result looks like this:



month_
nb_employees




2022-11-01
0


2022-12-01
1


2023-01-01
2


2023-02-01
3


2023-03-01
3


2023-04-01
3


2023-05-01
3


2023-06-01
2


...
...




Use a calendar table, then you can simply JOIN from that to your employee table.

Does this answer your question? Get all dates between two dates in SQL Server

As I mentioned in the comments, use a Calendar table; this makes it way easier. You can then just LEFT JOIN to your employee's table to get the count of users:
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20221101'; --Assumed this will always be the first of the month

SELECT C.CalendarDate AS Month,
       COUNT(ee.employee_id) AS Employees
FROM tbl.Calendar C
     LEFT JOIN dbo.employee_example ee ON C.CalendarDate >= ee.start_date
                                      AND C.CalendarDate < ee.leave_date
WHERE C.CalendarDate >= @StartDate
  AND C.CalendarDate < SYSDATETIME()
  AND C.CalendarDay = 1
GROUP BY C.CalendarDate;

If you don't have a Calendar table, create one. If you are really adverse to creating one (please do create one, they have so many uses!) then you can use a tally:
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20221101';

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT 0 AS I
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(MONTH,@StartDate, SYSDATETIME()))
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3), --1,000 months is more than enough
Months AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, T.I, @StartDate) AS Month
    FROM Tally T)
SELECT M.Month,
       COUNT(ee.employee_id) AS Employees
FROM Months M
     LEFT JOIN dbo.employee_example ee ON M.Month >= ee.start_date
                                      AND M.Month < ee.leave_date
GROUP BY M.Month;

If you're on 2022+ you can skip a couple steps and use GENERATE_SERIES:
DECLARE @StartDate date = '20221101';

WITH Months AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, GS.value, @StartDate) AS Month
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(0,DATEDIFF(MONTH,@StartDate, SYSDATETIME())) GS)
SELECT M.Month,
       COUNT(ee.employee_id) AS Employees
FROM Months M
     LEFT JOIN dbo.employee_example ee ON M.Month >= ee.start_date
                                      AND M.Month < ee.leave_date
GROUP BY M.Month;


You can do this with a recursive CTE
--Query using recursive CTE
WITH CTE as  
(
  SELECT CAST('2022-11-01' as DATE) as StartDate
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(month,1,c.StartDate)
  FROM CTE c
  WHERE  DATEADD(month,1,c.StartDate) < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  
)
SELECT c.StartDate, COUNT(e.employee_id)  as nb_employees
FROM CTE c
LEFT JOIN employee_example e on 
            (YEAR(e.start_date) < YEAR(c.startDate) OR (YEAR(e.start_date) = YEAR(c.startDate) AND MONTH(e.start_date) <= MONTH(c.startDate)))
             AND 
            (YEAR(e.leave_date) > YEAR(c.startDate) OR (YEAR(e.leave_date) = YEAR(c.startDate) AND MONTH(e.leave_date) >= MONTH(c.startDate)))
GROUP BY c.StartDate

fiddle



StartDate
nb_employees




2022-11-01
0


2022-12-01
1


2023-01-01
2


2023-02-01
3


2023-03-01
3


2023-04-01
3


2023-05-01
3


2023-06-01
2


2023-07-01
2


2023-08-01
2


2023-09-01
2


2023-10-01
2


2023-11-01
2


2023-12-01
2


2024-01-01
1


2024-02-01
1


2024-03-01
1


2024-04-01
1


2024-05-01
0




For a large range of dates a Tally would be much more performant.

watch out for MAXRECURSION

Loving the tally solution (now I understand how it works, I still thnk they would want it to cover a calander month like this:
--setup
declare @employees table 
    (
     [employee_id] int not null primary key 
    ,[first_name]   varchar(128) not null
    ,[last_name]    varchar(128) not null
    ,[start_date]   date not null 
    ,[leave_date]   date not null 
    ,unique ([first_name],[last_name])
    )
;
insert @employees 
    (
     [employee_id]
    ,[first_name]
    ,[last_name]
    ,[start_date]
    ,[leave_date]
    )   
select
     1
    ,'Example'
    ,'User'
    ,'2022-12-28'
    ,'2023-05-30'
union all
select
     2
    ,'Second'
    ,'Example'
    ,'2023-01-14'
    ,'2023-12-31'
union all
select
     3
    ,'Third'
    ,'Try'
    ,'2023-02-05'
    ,'2024-04-15'
union all
select
     4
    ,'fouth'
    ,'Try'
    ,'2023-02-05'
    ,'2024-04-15'
;
--answer, using my data, changed to get start / end dates from table and start on 1st of month
declare  @earliestDate date = (select min(dateadd(day,-1,[start_date])) from @employees) 
        ,@latestDate date = (select max(dateadd(month,1,[leave_date])) from @employees) 
        ;
declare  @firstDOM date = (select convert(date,dateadd(dd,-(day(@earliestDate)-1),@earliestDate))) 
    ;
with [N] AS
    (
    select N
    from (values(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null),(null)) [N] (N)
    ) -- 10 null rows
, [Tally] AS
(
    select 0 [I]
    union all
    select top(datediff(month,@firstDOM,@latestDate)) row_number() over (order by (select null)) [I]
    from 
        [N] [N1], [N] [N2], [N] [N3] --10 * 10 * 10 = 1000 --1,001 months is more than enough (0 indexed)
)
, [Months] as
(
    select 
        dateadd(month,[T].[I], @firstDOM) [Month]
    from 
        [Tally] [T]
)
select 
     [M].[Month]
    ,count([e].[employee_id]) [Employees]
from 
    [Months] [M]
left join 
    @employees [e] on [M].[Month] >= [e].[start_date] and [M].[Month] < [e].[leave_date]
group by 
    [M].[Month]
;


This is my solution, it avoids fixed start and ends dates as it derives them from the source table.  It also avoids a left join which might be slow over a large table.
--setup
declare @employees table 
    (
     [employee_id] int not null primary key 
    ,[first_name]   varchar(128) not null
    ,[last_name]    varchar(128) not null
    ,[start_date]   date not null 
    ,[leave_date]   date not null 
    ,unique ([first_name],[last_name])
    )
;
insert @employees 
    (
     [employee_id]
    ,[first_name]
    ,[last_name]
    ,[start_date]
    ,[leave_date]
    )   
select
     1
    ,'Example'
    ,'User'
    ,'2022-12-28'
    ,'2023-05-30'
union all
select
     2
    ,'Second'
    ,'Example'
    ,'2023-01-14'
    ,'2023-12-31'
union all
select
     3
    ,'Third'
    ,'Try'
    ,'2023-02-05'
    ,'2024-04-15'
union all
select
     4
    ,'fouth'
    ,'Try'
    ,'2023-02-05'
    ,'2024-04-15'
;
--solution
declare  @earliestDate date = (select min([start_date]) from @employees) 
        ,@latestDate date = (select max([leave_date]) from @employees) 
;
declare  @firstDOM date = (select convert(date,dateadd(dd,-(day(@earliestDate)-1),@earliestDate)))
        ;
with [dateRange] as  
(
  select 
    @firstDOM [date]
  union all
  select 
    dateadd(month,1,[dr].[date])
  from 
    [dateRange] [dr]
  where  
    dateadd(month,1,[dr].[date]) <= @latestDate 
)
, [startMonth] as 
(
select 
     year([start_date]) [start_year]
    ,month([start_date]) [start_month]
    ,count(*) [noOfStarts]
from 
    @employees 
group by
     year([start_date])
    ,month([start_date]) 
)
, [leaveMonth] as 
(
select 
     year([leave_date]) [leave_year]
    ,month([leave_date]) [leave_month]
    ,count(*) [noOfLeavers]
from 
    @employees 
group by
     year([leave_date])
    ,month([leave_date]) 
)
select
     year([dr].[date]) [year]
    ,month([dr].[date]) [month]
    ,coalesce((select [s].[noOfStarts] from [startMonth] [s] where year([dr].[date]) = [s].[start_year] and month([dr].[date]) = [s].[start_month]),0) [noOfStarts]
    ,coalesce((select [l].[noOfLeavers] from [leaveMonth] [l] where year([dr].[date]) = [l].[leave_year] and month([dr].[date]) = [l].[leave_month]),0) [noOfLeavers]
from
    [dateRange] [dr]
order by
     [year]
    ,[month]
;


" It also avoids a left join which might be slow over a large table." And instead uses a two subqueries, which would be resolved as LEFT JOIN in the plan, however, you now have two, not one, and the data engine may well process those jobs once per row from the outer scope, due to the way subqueries work in the SELECT. Notice there are 40 scans of the table: db<>fiddle
